# Is the function $f$ differentiable at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the  function $f$ given by

$$f(z) =\left\{  \begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z}, & \hbox{if }z\neq 0; \\
    0, & \hbox{if }z=0.
  \end{array}
\right.$$
differrentiable at $z=0$?

---

I start by taking the $$\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{\frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z}-0}{z-0}=\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{(\bar{z})^2}{z^2}$$

Choosing $z=x$, $\bar z=x$, thus $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$. Also by choosing $z=iy, \bar{z}=-iy$, $\lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{-y^2}{-y^2}=1$.

Hence, from the above the function $f$ is differentiable at $z = 0$.

Comment: Looks pretty continuous to me, which can be seen by noting that $|f(z)|=|z|$. However, **hint**: Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I hereby retract the Cauchy-Riemann hint -- Didier's argument showed me I had misplaced a sign along the way.

Comment: @Hassan To make a fancy-looking $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$ use `\lim\limits_{x\to 0}` or `\lim_{x \to 0}` for $\lim_{x \to 0}$

Comment: @PeterT.off: Thanks for the edit. Is my approach correct?

Comment: You should be careful to state whether you are considering [complex differentiability](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html) or real differentiability.

Comment: @WillieWong: What do you think I should do?

Comment: Edit the question to say whether by "differentiable" you mean it is "complex differentiable" (and hence solves the Cauchy-Riemann equations and is holomorphic), or you mean it is "real differentiable" as a function from the Euclidean plane to itself.

Comment: BTW, your edited approach is incorrect: just because a function has partial derivatives in two distinct directions does **not** mean it is (real) differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is $C^\infty$ everywhere except at $0$ and continuous at $0$ since, for example, $|f(x+\mathrm iy)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to0$ when $x+\mathrm iy\to0$, and $f(0)=0$.

But $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is not differentiable at $0$ because, for $h\to0$, $h$ real, $f(h)=h+o(h)$ and $f(\mathrm ih)=\mathrm ih+o(h)$ but $f((1+\mathrm i)h)=-(1+\mathrm i)h+o(h)\ne (1+\mathrm i)h+o(h)$.

Comment: No (lack of) holomorphy here, but a lack of differential at $(0,0)$.

Comment: What can you say about the differentiability of $f$ if $f:I\to \mathbb C$ where $I\in \mathbb C$?

Comment: ??? $ $ $ $ $ $